# Mysql GROUP BY query. Show data by date and hour

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table named "counter" that has 3 fields:

```
| Field  | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| record | datetime   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| passed | tinyint(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The data I store in record is like this(passed is boolean):

```
mysql> SELECT record, passed FROM counter;
+---------------------+--------+
| record              | passed |
+---------------------+--------+
| 2019-09-19 00:00:00 |      1 |
```

What I want to do is a query that summarizes how many times passed field had 1 grouped by the hour and date.
e.g.:

```
     Hour  | Date    |    passed
     13:00 2019-09-19      10
```

Executing:

```
SELECT HOUR (record), COUNT(*) as  passed FROM counter GROUP BY HOUR(record);
```

I get those results

```
| HOUR (record) | passed |
+---------------+--------+
|             0 |     67 |
|            13 |    199 |
+---------------+--------+
```

The problem is that there are records after 13:00, not sowing at all.

Also in order to get also the date I have tried:

```
SELECT DAY(record), COUNT(*), HOUR(record), COUNT(*) as  passed FROM counter GROUP BY HOUR(record);
```

And I get this error

```
ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'iot.counter.record' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

How can I archive the wanted result?

Comment: Simply add `DAY(record)` to the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Your first query looks alright, can you show a sample dataset and the results you are getting from it

Comment: A [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with your structure and sample data would be very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind having a single field for the date and time, then `DATE_FORMAT` can be used here:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(record, '%Y-%m-%d %H') AS ts,
    COUNT(*) AS passed
FROM counter
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(record, '%Y-%m-%d %H');
```

Comment: Single _column_, consisting of year, month etc _fields_.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(record, '%Y-%m-%d) as dt,
DATE_FORMAT(record, '%h:%i) as ts,
COUNT(*) AS passed
FROM counter
GROUP BY 
DATE_FORMAT(record, '%Y-%m-%d) as dt,
DATE_FORMAT(record, '%h:%i) as ts;
```